# Comparing and counting arrays

Tags: java, c#, arrays

I am currently working on a fake drivers education test. As expected the user has to answer 20 questions, if the user gets 15 or more questions correct the user passes. If the user gets 15 or less questions correct the user fails.

Design: [URL to a picture of my current GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouGR3.jpg)

So far, with the help of Google, I have implemented my key array

```
        string[] key = new string[20];
        key[0] = "B";
        key[1] = "D";
        key[2] = "A";
        key[3] = "A";
        key[4] = "C";
        key[5] = "A";
        key[6] = "B";
        key[7] = "A";
        key[8] = "C";
        key[9] = "D";
        key[10] = "B";
        key[11] = "C";
        key[12] = "D";
        key[13] = "A";
        key[14] = "D";
        key[15] = "C";
        key[16] = "C";
        key[17] = "B";
        key[18] = "D";
        key[19] = "A";
```

I also have the user created array that will be created as the user inputs their answers into the textboxes along with the output array to display the inputs, although I don't think I'll need it:

```
        // User input
        string[] values = new string[20];

        values[0] = textBox1.Text;
        values[1] = textBox2.Text;
        values[2] = textBox3.Text;
        values[3] = textBox4.Text;
        values[4] = textBox5.Text;
        values[5] = textBox6.Text;
        values[6] = textBox7.Text;
        values[7] = textBox8.Text;
        values[8] = textBox9.Text;
        values[9] = textBox10.Text;
        values[10] = textBox11.Text;
        values[11] = textBox12.Text;
        values[12]= textBox13.Text;
        values[13] = textBox14.Text;
        values[14] = textBox15.Text;
        values[15] = textBox16.Text;
        values[16] = textBox17.Text;
        values[17] = textBox18.Text;
        values[18] = textBox19.Text;
        values[19] = textBox20.Text;

        // Displays selection (may not be needed)
        textBox1.Text = values[0];
        textBox2.Text = values[1];
        textBox3.Text = values[2];
        textBox4.Text = values[3];
        textBox4.Text = values[4];
        textBox6.Text = values[5];
        textBox7.Text = values[6];
        textBox8.Text = values[7];
        textBox9.Text = values[8];
        textBox10.Text = values[9];
        textBox11.Text = values[10];
        textBox12.Text = values[11];
        textBox13.Text = values[12];
        textBox14.Text = values[13];
        textBox15.Text = values[14];
        textBox16.Text = values[15];
        textBox17.Text = values[16];
        textBox18.Text = values[17];
        textBox19.Text = values[18];
        textBox20.Text = values[19];
```

My question is two fold:

1.) How do I go about comparing the values array against the Key array in such a manner that if the user inputted D instead of B that array [0] would be counted wrong?

2.) How would I go about displaying the "correct" and "wrong" arrays.

If my questions are to vague, not precises enough, or I need to provide more information please ask. I am only asking for some advice and guidance. Thank You

Comment: You have too much code repetition. Moreover, you are going to have even more. You need to use some OOP in order to not look it like it is 20-times copy-paste. As for me, I would recomment implementing custom **WinForms control** which will be initialized with a question, answers and right answer. Then, this control would inherit the logic or displaying question, answers, "correct", "incorrect" etc.

Comment: How does Java come into picture here?

Comment: Please do clarify. Answers to both questions seems obvious. You compare values here the same way you would anywhere: by using some kind of comparison operator, e.g. `==`. And you can display values in the usual way: by presenting them in the user interface. What have you tried? Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you've tried, and a precise explanation of what that code does, and how that's different from what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help :

```
String key[] = {"B","C","A","C"};
        String values[] = {"B","C","B","A"};
        int marks=0;
        for(int i=0 ; i<key.length ; i++) {
            if(key[i].equals(values[i])) {
                System.out.println("Correct Answer");
                ++marks; 
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Wrong!!!!!.For Question "+i+" Answer is "+key[i]);
            }

            if(marks>=15) {
                System.out.println("Congratzzz!!You passed.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Sorry!!You couldnt make it.");
            }
        }
```